# Print a dictionary and save it to a file, then copy it to a py file to use?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

Using a DB, I want to create a very large dictionary. If I save it to disk, when pickled, it takes about 10 MB of space.

What I want to do is:

Save this dictionary as it is to disk, in order to open up that text document and copy it to another py file so that I won't have to re-generate it each time and whenever the py document is called via web app, it is iterable.

How can I do this?

PS. My app is running on Google app engine and I want to solve this issue like this to refrain from DB et al resource usage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

store it into the blobstore via files api:

```
class YourDictModel(ndb.Model):
    data = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()

huge_dict = dict(...)

file_name = files.blobstore.create(mime_type='application/octet-stream')
with files.open(file_name, 'a') as f:
    f.write(marshal.dumps(huge_dict))

    # Finalize the file. Do this before attempting to read it.
    files.finalize(file_name)

    # Get the file's blob key
    blob_key = files.blobstore.get_blob_key(file_name)
    entity = YourDictModel(data = blob_key)

    entity.put()
```

notice that:

- you can't modify a blob so to modify it you will need to read the dict
  into memory, delete the blob, create a new one and replace the key on
  the model.
- the bigger the dictionary the more likely you will hit
  the soft process size limit.
- i use marshal but you can use pickle,
  json or whatever you prefer.

**you can't write to file from the GAE SDK:
[how to write or create (when no exist) a file using python and Google AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680215/how-to-write-or-create-when-no-exist-a-file-using-python-and-google-appengine)**

Comment: Good call on marshal, it is the fastest and most compact of the three. If blobstore isn't fast enough for you, you could chop the string returned by marshal up in 1M-sized blocks and write those to memcache with some kind of systematic set of keys. You can write/read to 32M of data to/from memcache using put_multi()/get_multi() as long as each value is under 1M.

Answer (score 1):

First, if your dictionary pickled take 10MB, it will probably use more space than that if you store it plain in a py file. If your dictionary only contains basic types you can use just a plain print

```
>>> print 'mydict = %s' %({'a': [1,2], 2: 'c'}, )
mydict = {'a': [1, 2], 2: 'c'}
```

Consider also that the loading time of such file will be considerable.

Second, What you want to do is not possible using Google App Engine because you cannot dynamically change the sources of your project. Unless that dictionary is never going to change.

Google app engine has free quotas even for the Datastore, so I don't see the point of trying to bypass it.

Comment: Hello. I am creating on my dev. machine a very large TRIE from a DB. I want this to be stored as a dictionary in memory so that I gain time. Creating this tree takes a bit of a time from the DB so I want it to be in a py file so whenever the file called, it will be already in memory waiting to be used. I want to achieve this on my dev computer and just upload the py to the server. I know how to print the dict but how can I create a utf-8 plain text document where it's written?

Comment: The problem with this solution is that is no guarantee that your instances will be up all the time, so whenever GAE creates a new instance it will take a considerable time to load. What's your use case, if you are using tries I imagine you want to perform some sort of search, in which case the Full Text search api could be useful.
For creating the file you can use fd = open('mytrie.py', 'w') fd.write('mytrie = %s' %(mytrie, )) fd.close(). And then just do in your code from mytrie import mytrie

Comment: I will check the full text search option as a solution in this use case. Also thank you very much for explaining what I was looking for. Very kind of you, thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want a dump of the dictionary that you can load as python. That's fairly easy:

```
>>> d = {'key': 'value'}
>>> print '%r' % (d, )
{'key': 'value'}
>>> print repr(d)
{'key': 'value'}
>>> open('/tmp/mydict.py', 'w').write(repr(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

The max acceptable size for a file on GAE is 10,485,760 bytes.

[Uploading, Downloading, and Managing a Python App - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp)

Also, a dictionary of that size doesn't sound very efficient. What you save in data store calls you might lose in the number of instance hours required to run your app.

In the end you'd probably be better off from a cost and performance standpoint to just use the data store.

Comment: That limit is for application files.  If he's trying to generate a file, he can store a larger file in the BlobStore.

Comment: Or I can divide into two py files. But that's not my concern. My concern is, I fail to understand how to print a dictionary into a unicode text document on my own development computer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save to disk in App Engine.  The closest equivalent would be to pickle and save to the blobstore.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/

You'll have to do your own tests to see if the performance is worth it, but the Blobstore may be cheaper than issuing queries to regenerate this data over and over.

Comment: I want to do this on my dev. machine to be uploaded as only a py file to the server. How can I write this large dict. into a plain text utf8 file? That's what I really wonder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I can't see why you would want to try to do this so can't come up with an idea that might help.

Can you clarify what your trying to do instead of what your wanting to do?

Although if I am understanding you correctly what your wanting to do is get around resource usage.  There is no way to avoid using GAE resources if your using the platform.  No matter what you do your going to hit some type of resource usage on App Engine.  You either put the dictionary in the datastore, blobstore, or memcache.  You can send the data to another url, you can download and upload the data but you are still using resources.

Comment: I've a DB table sort of like a word list. I perform frequent complex lookup algorithms on it. SQL is slow and takes a lot of memory. My solution: convert it to a TRIE, store it in a custom hash-table of dictionaries and use that. Creating it means going through DB and it is too long. I want to avoid this for each look up. I want the TRIE to be stored in memory, created only once and accessed many times. Since this is a web app, 10 people might make 10 requests to use it. And it takes more than 1 MB in memory, more like 10. However, I can distribute it in case of memcache.

Comment: Why not compute the file in production?  You can use the [backend service](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) to do calcs that won't fit into the 1 minute request limit.  Then you can use memcache to make the app more efficient. The only other thing I can think of is using JSON to upload the data to the server, you will still have to dump it into the blobstore and memcache. JSONPickle is something I have seen in posts https://github.com/jsonpickle/jsonpickle I have not used it. Here is a post JSON vs Pickle http://kovshenin.com/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/